# When is the first recorded use of dark matter in the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, technology

Question as stated. With a bit more spoiler-filled elaboration:

> The Resistance leadership, even with whatever technical training they possessed, thought it was impossible for dark matter to be amassed and used this way at Starkiller Base, yet Finn assured them it is very much true. Folks like Admiral Ackbar were senior military commanders since the Clone Wars at the latest, so for them to say that would suggest such usage has not been recorded in military history.

As such, there's two parts to this question:

- Does the ability to harness dark matter for technological use already exist in the universe?
- If yes to the previous question, then has dark matter been used in practical technology before (the ability to harvest is distinct from the ability to use to practical effect)?

> The last question can be separated into whether it has ever been used or if it has only seen usage at a smaller scale.

Comment: I should point out that it's not "dark matter" that the Starkiller base uses but "dark energy".

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, it was "Dark Energy", not "Dark Matter":

> Having been gathered in stages by an immense array of coupled collectors located on the other side of the planet, a tremendously compact volume of **a type of dark energy known as quintessence** had been accumulated at the center of the planet. (*Foster novelization*).

Notably, the term isn't used in the film's script/dialog, only in novelization.

### Assuming this was [meant in purely physics context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy):

Uncertain but probably yes, the first one.

- Resistance (as in, THE Admiral Akbar) thinks it's impossible:

  > “As near as I understand it,” Finn continued, “enormous arrays of specially designed collectors use the power of a sun to attract and send dark energy to a containment unit at the core of the planet, where it is held and built up inside that containment unit until the weapon is ready to fire.”
  > “**Impossible,” Ackbar insisted.** “Although we know there is more dark energy in the universe than anything else, and that it exists everywhere around us, **it is so diffuse that it can barely be detected. Let alone concentrated.**”
- None of my text searches revealed "Dark Energy" used for anything.

  - Nothing in notable superweapons (Sun Crusher, Galaxy Gun, Centerpoint Station, Rakata Star Forge)
  - Nothing on Wookieepedia
  - Nothing in any books I've read.

---

### In the Force context

Having said that, there's a strong implication that "Dark Energy" may refer to "Dark Side" and not particle physics, merely because the use of the Starkiller weapon is always linked - especially in novelization, - with darkness, both moral and even physical.

If that is indeed the case, then Rakata did use something similar - Star Forge was powered by energy of the Sun infused with Dark Side of the Force.

In this context, we can also count things that various EU sources called "Dark Side energy":

- [Dark side Burst](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_side_burst) (Sidious, Joruus C'Baoth)
- [Dark Side Web](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Odojinya)
- Dark side energy in [Freedon Nadd's tomb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Freedon_Nadd)
- Dark side energy released by accident to destroy [Ambria](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ambria)